# Kotlin Dagger - Inject Fragment values into viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

I need a solution where i could inject Fragment arguments/extras (one `Long`and one `String` to be specific) into Fragment's viewmodel and based on these values viewmodel could run it's setup in `init {..}`

All the ViewModel's injections are fine, dependencies in ViewModel's `@Inject construct([dependencies]){..}` are provided and working correctly.

My SubComponent looks like this at the moment :

`

```
@Scope
annotation class MyFragmentScope

@MyFragmentScope
@Subcomponent(modules = [MyFragmentModule::class])
interface MyFragmentSubcomponent : Injector<MyFragment> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder : Injector.Factory<MyFragment>
}

@Module
abstract class MyFragmentModule {

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @MyFragmentScope
    @ViewModelKey(MyFragmentViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindMyFragmentViewModel(
        viewModel: MyFragmentViewModel
    ): ViewModel
}
```

`

I would be super thankful for any support
Cheers

I tried to create a new ViewModelFactory with additional parameter, but sadly that didn't work out

Tried to use Hilt or Assisted Injection, which also didn't work out since my project is strictly restricted to Dagger v 2.16, if i try to update - tons of bugs arise from this old codebase, it would take months rewriting everything.

Maybe i just did something wrong

Comment: Does the setup need to be absolutely strictly run in the constructor of the view model?

Comment: @TheLibrarian I would say no, i just want to pass my Fragment's arguments to viewmodel in the cleanest form of code possible. In my imagination the perfect way would be to pass the arguments to viewmodel once fragment crates it's own viewmodel, therefore i have no need to call any functions from fragment to viewmodel afterwards, just to pass the values i need.

Comment: Well, for what you want you would need Hilt but since that is not an option. Having an initialization function is not some cardinal sin that will hunt you till the day you die. It's ok to use and it is going to be the cleanest way how to do it(You can create a factory that will have input the argument and it will be able to pass it in the constructor but it is going to do the same with 10times the code).